# What is wrong with this proj4 string that the raster package in R will not accept?

Tags: raster, r

I am trying to use a .tif file from USDA's CropScape, which has the proj4 string

> "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0
> +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"

Creating the original raster object succeeds and is plottable, but comes along with the error message

> "Warning message: In .newCRS(value) :   +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5
> +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 is not a valid PROJ.4 CRS string"

Likewise, trying to manually assign the CRS by typing

```
crs(cropscape) <- "proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

does not work and returns a similar error message, that it is not a valid PROJ.4 CRS string.

I'm no CRS or PROJ4 genius but I do not see what is wrong with this string. What is the problem here?

For reproducability: this is the code being used to generate the cropscape raster object:

```
cropscape <- GET(url="https://nassgeodata.gmu.edu",
                 path="axis2/services/CDLService/GetCDLFile?year=2014&fips=06") %>%
  content('text') %>%
  str_remove(".*<returnURL>") %>%
  str_remove("</returnURL>.*") %>%
  raster()
```

Comment: Where does `GET` and the `%>%` operator  come from?

Comment: Sorry, GET is from package httr and is being used to interface with the cropscape API. %>% is a piping operator from dplyr.

Comment: and `str_remove`? If you are going for reproducibility you do need to tell us all the add-on packages.

Comment: from stringr, also a part of tidyverse. Sorry for not including this off the bat, I was under the impression that tidyverse was universal enough that these would be recognized. GET pulls the info from the API, content strips everything but the text, which is a string from which I want just a url that is surrounded by <returnURL> and </returnURL> tags

Comment: No, its not universal! And anyway, doing `library(tidyverse)` is never a good idea - best practice is to always use as few packages as possible and get each one with a separate `library` call.

Comment: The code gives me an OPeNDAP error: `Error in .local(.Object, ...) : 
  An error occurred while creating a virtual connection to the DAP server:
Error while reading the URL: https://nassgeodata.gmu.edu/webservice/nass_data_cache/byfips/CDL_2014_06.tif.ver. [...]`. The output from the pipe that goes into `raster` is the URL `https://nassgeodata.gmu.edu/webservice/nass_data_cache/byfips/CDL_2014_06.tif` which fails when passed to `raster` but I can `download.file` but its 910Mb which I'm not downloading. How big is the resulting raster?

Comment: This is probably an issue with the move to PROJ6 and GDAL3. If you have a newer version of rgdal installed you will run into issues with proj strings. It is now encouraged to use EPSG codes to define the crs. So if you have any spatial code instead of the proj string it would be better to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Your CRS:

```
> crs(r) <- "proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
Warning message:
In .newCRS(value) :
  proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 is not a valid PROJ.4 CRS string
```

Works if you add a + sign at the start:

```
> crs(r) <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
>
```

Interestingly the `sf` package seems to cope with it:

```
> pts = st_as_sf(data.frame(x=1,y=1),coords=1:2)
> st_crs(pts) <- "proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
```

but is silently setting the CRS to NA:

```
> pts
Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 0 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1 ymin: 1 xmax: 1 ymax: 1
CRS:            NA
```

Some of this behaviour might be different on newer versions of GDAL with newer versions of PROJ - lots of CRS handling has changed.

Comment: I think I made a mistake transcribing this to stackexchange. My original code does have a leading plus sign and still generates the error
```
crs(cropscape) <- "+proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"
Warning message:
In .newCRS(value) :
  +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0 is not a valid PROJ.4 CRS string